# Disable browser platform / login on browser platform

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a meteor app that I want to only release on mobile platforms (iPhone and Android), so that when you type the server's address, you don't get to use the app and, more precisely, call methods using the javascript console. But the server part still has to be functional.

I figured when you type the server URL, I would just display a homepage to present the app instead of the app itself, so I fiddled with the iron router :

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});

if (Meteor.isServer || Meteor.isCordova) {
    // mobile app routes and behaviors
}
```

In the layout template, I only yield if the client is Cordova :

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="page-container">
  {{#if isCordova}}
    {{> header}}
    {{> flashMessages}}
    <div id="main" class="container">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <!-- Static presentation -->
  {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

`isCordova` is a simple UI helper returning `Meteor.isCordova`.

Now the page looks nice and sweet, but the downer is this: `Meteor.loginWithPassword` can still be called within the console, and from there a registered user can basically do anything he or she could do from the mobile app by calling the server methods. My server methods do check if the user is logged in, but can't figure out from which platform... as far as I know.

Is there any way to disable this? My app depends strongly on user geolocation and I don't want to make it too easy for them to fake-up their position. (I know faking position can also be achieved on mobile phones, but I gotta concede stuff if I ever want to finish this... thing)

Comment: Opening the console is not something you expect an average user to do. Remember that no matter what you do, there will always be a way to misuse your server API. It is just a matter of how hard it will be.

Comment: That is why I am assuming it is way too easy/uncommitting to install a firefox add-on like Geolocater than to start rooting your phone. Same reason apps like Snapchat or Tinder don't have a browser app. Smartphones are way more controlled environments than PCs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [validateLoginAttempt](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt) to filter out unwanted connections:

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (attempt) {
   if (!attempt.allowed) { // login failed for some other reason
     return false;
   }       
   /* you can now check user agent by accessing
      attempt.connection.httpHeaders['User-Agent']
      and return false if you don't like it
   */
});
```

Comment: Interesting take on the issue. But I assume user agent modifiers on browsers can fake this property. I wish there was something more radical, like `meteor remove-platform browser`

Comment: Do you want to disable the login for security or usability reasons?

Comment: Usability reasons. Let's say being able to fake your position (which is sent to the server by the client) defeats the purpose of my app. Not security since there is little threat to confidentiality at stake, unless I consider located data as confidential to people who are not in that data's designated area.

Comment: Well, then I guess there is almost nothing you can do to entirely protect yourself from the type of users who will struggle to fake that data. Are you really expecting this type of behavior from your users? I would guess that most of them wouldn't even know how to use developer console, not even mentioning replacing the user agent. But maybe it's just me who thinks that way :)